# View Switching Navigation using Prism,MVVM,Unity

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, prism, unity-container

```
container.RegisterType<object, LabStatusView>("LabStatusView");
Uri LabStatusViewUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LabStatus;component/LabStatusView.xaml",     
UriKind.Absolute);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("HorizonNavigatorView",LabStatusViewUri,NavigationCompleted);
```

I am using this to navigate to LabStatusView, which seems straightforward.

ObjectStates after the requestNavigate is executed:

1. regionManager.Regions.ActiveRegion contains one object of type "Object" instead of LabStatusView.
2. The only quirk of using Unity known to me is that i have register my type using overload of RegiterType method.

Any suggestion what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Navigate is alot easier to do than in your code. Here's how i did it for a project.

```
//Register your View on Startup
container.RegisterType<object, LabStatusView>("LabStatusView");

//Navigation works like this
var labStatusView = new Uri("LabStatusView", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("HorizonNavigatorView", labStatusView);
```

Can you try it like this?

Also many people use static classes for their Region and View name to avoid "magic strings".
Something like this.

```
public class RegionNames
{
  public const string HorizonNavigatorView = "HorizonNavigatorView";
}
public class ViewNames
{
  public const string LabStatusView = "LabStatusView";
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use just LabStatusView in the URI constructor as it resides in different assembly. That's why I needed to use pack: format. I tried this but it didn't work. After navigating it always have a reference of type object.

Comment: I found what i was missing. the name that we use to register with the container is the name that i use when i create the URI. they have to be same. I thought i have to give the path to the class while creating the URI.

Comment: Thank you for the `object` type mapping--that made all the difference for me